# Getting error while converting base64 string into image using pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, base64, pyarrow

I want to extract and process an image data (3D array) available in base64 format using pyspark. I'm using pandas_udf with pyarrow as a processing function. While parsing the base64 string into pandas_udf function, first I convert the base64 string into image. But, at this step I'm getting error as "TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str."

I am using function base64.b64decode(imgString) to convert base64 string to image. I'm using python 2.7

...

```
avrodf=sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("hdfs:///Raw_Images_201803182350.avro")
interested_cols = ["id","name","image_b64"]
indexed_avrodf = avrodf.select(interested_cols)
ctx_cols = ["id","name"]
result_sdf = indexed_avrodf.groupby(ctx_cols).apply(img_proc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id",StringType()),
    StructField("name",StringType()),
    StructField("image",StringType()),
    StructField("Proc_output",StringType())
])

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def img_proc(df):
    df['Proc_output'] = df['image_b64'].apply(is_processed)
    return df

def is_processed(imgString):
    import cv2
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageChops
    import base64

    wisimg = base64.b64decode(imgString)
    image = Image.open(wisimg)

    .....

    return processed_status
```

Comment: You will obtain an answer if you can provide a copy/paste-able MCVE that the community can easily run and see the problem for themselves.  Is it possible to [isolate the problem](http://sscce.org/) you are having to a few lines of code?